# How can my code remember user input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a program that will eventually be used in a chrome extension that will launch every time you open a new tab, essentially all I want it to do is display the time and "hello, *your name*."

Right now i have it set up so the code prompts for the user to enter their name, it stores that value in a variable, and places that within an anchor tag in the html. This is great, matter of fact, it is exactly what I want, but the only issue is that every time the page is refreshed, the user needs to enter their name again. You can probably see where that may be an issue.

So my question is this: is it possible to make my code remember the user's name and print that out every time that page is opened instead of needing to re-enter it every time. If we could keep this to pure js that would be preferable, but I'm always open to other solutions.

my code looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function clock() {
       var now = new Date();
       var outStr = now.getHours()+':'+now.getMinutes()+':'+now.getSeconds();
       document.getElementById('clockA').innerHTML=outStr;
       setTimeout('clock()',1000);
    }

        function name() {
            var name = prompt("What's your name?");

            document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = "Hello," + " " + name;
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload='clock(); name();'>

    <div id=time-parent>
        <a id="clockA"></a>
        <p id="hello"></p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try using `localStorage`

Comment: Or cookies. Do you have any server side scripting available, by the way?

Comment: however, for an annoying extension that will remind you of your own name every time you open a tab, `localStorage` or `cookies` is probably not the best storage - google has some documentation for developers who wish to create such useful extensions, refer to the documentation for the best solution

Comment: @EthanBeigh See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

Comment: @j08691 not completely sure what you're talking about, i'm still pretty new to js and jquery, could you elaborate?

Comment: You had originally tagged your question with jQuery, however there was no jQuery posted, just plain JavaScript.

Comment: @j08691 oh, sorry. I'm still new here, didn't really realize that you shouldn't put tags on something unless it's completely relevant. The only other place is use tags for anything is things like tumblr where you want as many tags as possible.

Comment: As a side note, you will have to change your JavaScript since [inline JS](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution) isn't allowed in Chrome extensions.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `localstorage`. To use this, refer to [This Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage). Don't worry about anything but the first block of code.